# Why is it Mandatory to say “Peace be upon Him” whenever mentioning the Prophets name but not Subhanahu wa ta'ala whenever mentioning Allah’s name?

Tags: allah, prophet-muhammad, salawat

I always see PBUH (Peace be upon him) after the names of the Prophet but not SWT ( Subhanahu wa ta'ala) after Allah’s name.

Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

The prophet specifically condemned those who don’t send salam to him after mentioning him:

> Allah’s messenger said: “May he be abased he who does not invoke a blessing on me when I am mentioned in his presence”  
> Grade: Sahih - Al Albani  
> **[ [Sunnah Ref: Mishkat al Masabih 927](https://sunnah.com/mishkat:927) ]**

but there is no condemnation for the one who mentions Allah without praising him and actions are permissible unless proven impermissible.

We also know there are thousands of instances in which the prophet and sahabah mentioned Allah without an accompanied honorific/prayer.